# Checking database with parsley remote validation

Tags: parsley.js

I am trying to see if a table exists in this database using parsley remote validation, but I am not receiving the external php data, only `200 OK` or `404` error codes. Is there any way to get the data I echo like 0 or 1 and compare it in the JS?

```
<input type="text" name="aux_tablas" data-parsley-remote data-parsley-remote-validator="aux_tablas" data-parsley-remote-options='{ "type": "GET", "dataType": "jsonp", "data": { "tipo": "aux_tablas" } }' />


<script type="text/javascript">
$('#form_principal').parsley()
  .addAsyncValidator('aux_tablas', function (xhr) {
    return 404 === xhr.status;
  }, '<?=$datos_configuracion->path?>protected/motor/busqueda.php');
</script>
```

The external php is answering with 1 or 0 and that's working, but I don't know how to make it validate. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. If exists answers with 200, so its invalid, if not exists, works with 404, so:

In the external file, you should put if not exists header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");